# Can multiple microinverters, connected in parallel to a single source, become unstable?

Tags: batteries, control, inverter, mppt

Just to get this out of the way, I realize that what I'm exploring is well outside the design specs for the hardware I'm using. Now that that's out of the way:

I have a large lithium battery module that I'd like to turn into a battery storage system. Ultimately, the goal is to take energy from the battery and put it into my building mains. Conveniently, I have several solar microinverters as well, but each is only capable of 250W maximum. I'd like to put them in parallel with the battery, but I'm concerned by the fact that each microinverter has MPPT capabilities (being designed for solar applications). To be clear, the battery is providing power to the microinverters.

In theory, the MPPT algorithm should optimize the load on the battery so that it matches the load impedance to the battery's source impedance. I don't know enough about how an MPPT system is implemented to understand the effect of multiple control loops acting in parallel on the same system.

I doubt this would cause problems since each microinverter is designed to self-protect, and the battery is unlikely to sustain damage from a varying load, but I am curious whether the control loops would become unstable due to their parallel operation, and how I can avoid this instability.

EDIT: Since it seems to be confusing, I've added the diagram below to make it clear how the system is connected. *There are no other connections to the microinverter*, meaning there is no battery charger or other DC output. There is no AC input for charging either. It is entirely unidirectional.

[image: System Diagram]

Comment: You might insert a 0.1ohm resistor between each module and the battery.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf Can you explain why a small-value resistor would stabilize MPPT algorithms in parallel? Also, I'm assuming you are talking about the microinverters when you say "module." I used the term "module" to refer to the battery.

Comment: A battery has a very low impedance. Why would you want to use an MPPT inverter from the battery - are you trying to drain it as quickly as possible? Or is it just because you have these inverters and don't need the MPPT feature?

Comment: I hope you're not proposing tying their outputs together.

Comment: To clarify - these inverters have three connections, right? Solar, battery, and mains?

Comment: MPPT algorithm is NOT designed to match impedances. The MPPT algorithm is designed to run a solar panel at the single voltage which produces maximum solar panel power output. So it controls the solar panel output current up and down until it finds the maximum power point of the solar panel. It is anyone's guess what it will do with a battery as a power source. But it will probably not match the source impedance with the load impedance, and you wouldn't want it to. What are you ACTUALLY trying to do? Update the question, don't reply in the comment section.

Comment: Basically, if you want to convert your battery voltage to mains voltage, you are going to have to get a normal DC to AC inverter. It is crazy to try to do it with micro-inverters designed totally for something else.

Comment: @immibis I have the inverters and don't need the MPPT functionality. Also, the inverters have two connections: Solar DC (MC4 connections) and AC (hot-hot-neutral-ground in a proprietary cable/connector).

Comment: @SimonRichter The inverters are actually designed to have their outputs tied. They are not designed, however, to have their inputs tied.

Comment: @mkeith I added the ultimate goal to the question. I'm aware of what MPPT is *supposed* to do, but this is obviously outside the normal design specs. Also, these are "normal" DC-AC inverters... They're also intended for grid-tied operation, which is something most inverters don't have, except in the multi-kW range.

Comment: I can't speak for the inverter side, but the MPPT feature will be totally dormant since there's no power coming in from the solar panels (that you don't have). The MPPT is in-between the solar panels and the battery, not between the battery and the mains.

Comment: The MPPT algorithm is specifically designed to accommodate the V-I curve of a solar panel. When connected to a battery the behavior may be unpredictable. It may even simply draw more and more current from the battery until it self-destructs or blows a fuse. Who knows? The manufacturer may know. You could try asking them. Let me ask you something: how much current do you want each micro-inverter to draw from the battery? Also, does this need to pass inspection? Because I can't see a building inspector approving it.

Comment: @immibis If it wasn't clear in the question, I am powering the DC side of the inverter with the *battery*. I am not charging the battery with an inverter...

Comment: @mkeith It does not need to pass an inspection. Also, I know it won't suffer from excess current because each inverter limits its input to ~1A. The manufacturer is also extremely poor at communicating with end users. It barely even provides support to system installers.